# NSURLConnection hangs on recieving not too big amount od data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection, nsurlconnection, ios4

I have some code here:

```
(...)
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

and delegate methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{   
    NSLog(@"zero");
   [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"got %d", [data length]);
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    [connection release];
    [webData release];      
}
```

It works pretty good untill more data has to come.
Than NSURLConnection "stop working" (with no error, no exception, no quit). I can still use my app. 
I noticed that problem begin when `didReceiveData` is being called more than once during the connection.

How it looks like step by step from debugger:

```
1. I call theRequest
2. Delegate call didReceiveResponse
```

2010-06-21 18:10:16.708 MyApp[9477:207] zero

```
3. Delegate call didReceiveData
```

2010-06-21 18:10:16.709 MyApp[9477:207] got 6912

(gdb) continue

```
4. Delegate call didReceiveData (once again)
```

2010-06-21 18:10:18.027 MyApp[9477:207] got 114067

(gdb) continue

```
--> and here is the problem <--
```

main loop continue with no breakpoint, and `connectionDidFinishLoading` is not called. 
Everything is ok when didRecieveData is being called just once.

```
5. Delegate call didFailWithError (after 5 min!)
```

2010-06-21 18:15:18.041 MyApp[9477:207] ERROR with theConenction
Connection failed! Error - The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer

(gdb) continue

**=============== UPDATE ====================**

Finally, I have discovered one important thing: True problem is that remote host doesn't finish connection in proper way sometimes (ie. big amount of data), so delegate connectionDidFinishLoading can't be called and after 5 min remote host reset connection.

Has anyone the problem too and can help?

Comment: Have you tried loading a big chunk of data from another server? Is this specific-server related? The default timer for iPhone SDK when using POST request is quite long. And it stays long no matter what you enter. I ended up making my own timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've workarounded the issue using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Answer (score 0):

If you put on breakpoints, does say where it has stopped?

Comment: there are breakpoints, but after some loops it freezes with no reaction on breakpoint and XCode notice bar shows "Running..." 
But what is important the main thread of the program doesn't freze - I can use my app